# For what $\alpha$ does $\iint_D\frac{1}{(x+y)^{\alpha}}\ dxdy$ converge?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> For what values of $\alpha$ does $$\iint_D\frac{1}{(x+y)^{\alpha}}\
>  dxdy$$ converge? $D=\{0\leq y \leq 1-x, \quad 0 \leq \ x \leq 1\}.$

The double integral can be written as

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1-x} \frac{1}{(x+y)^{\alpha}} \ dy\right)dx.$$

How does one find a primitive to the inner integral?

Comment: The definition of $D$ gives a set that is different to the $D$ implied by the iterated integrals. I guess the definition is wrong (it should be $0\le y\le 1-x$), and the iterated integrals are OK. But better you tell me. ;)

Comment: In fact, according to the definition, it would be $D=\{(1,0)\}$.

Comment: Iterated integrals can exist while the double integral (as an integral with respect to the two-dimensional product measure) diverges.  Written as $\int \int_D$ I suspect the question refers to the latter.

Comment: It is supposed to be $1-x$, you guys are correct. I'll edit that. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by converge. is it a generalised integral.

Comment: Yes, since $f$ becames unbouded near $(0,0)$ and so the 'Riemann' integral is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\frac1{(x+y)^\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\int_x^1\frac1{t^\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^t\frac1{t^\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}t\tag2\\
&=\int_0^1t^{1-\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag3\\
&=\frac1{2-\alpha}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $y=t-x$
$(2)$: change order of integration
$(3)$: integrate in $x$
$(4)$: integrate in $t$, integral converges iff $1-a\gt-1$

Thus, the integral converges iff $\alpha\lt2$.

---

**Primitive of the Inner Integral**
$$
\int\frac1{(x+y)^\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}y=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\frac1{1-\alpha}(x+y)^{1-\alpha}+C&\text{if $\alpha\ne-1$}\\
\log|x+y|+C&\text{if $\alpha=-1$}
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: But why does it converge if $\alpha < 2?$ If for example $\alpha = -8$, we still get a real number so it's converging there too?

Comment: Yes. If $a=-8$, then the integral is $\int_0^1t^9\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac1{10}$. You do know that $\int_0^1t^b\,\mathrm{d}t$ converges iff $b\gt-1$?

Answer (score 2):

In general, the answer might depend on whether this is considered to be the integral over a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the product measure,

$$\tag{1}I = \int_D (x+y)^{-\alpha}$$

or as iterated integrals

$$\tag{2} J= \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^{1-x} (x+y)^{-\alpha} \, dy \right) \, dx $$

In this case it doesn't matter, but I will answer with reference to (1).

The diagonal boundary of the region of integration falls in  between circular arcs with radii $1/2$ and $1$.

Since the integrand is nonnegative,

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{1/2} \frac{r \, dr \, d\theta}{r^\alpha(\cos \theta + \sin \theta)^\alpha} \leqslant I \leqslant \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{1} \frac{r \, dr \, d\theta}{r^\alpha(\cos \theta + \sin \theta)^\alpha}$$

Note that $\cos \theta + \sin \theta > 0$ for $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$ which implies that

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d \theta }{(\cos \theta + \sin \theta)^{\alpha}},$$

converges for all $\alpha$.

Thus, we have convergence of $I$ if $\alpha < 2$ and divergence if $\alpha \geqslant 2$, determined  by the convergence/divergence of

$$\int_0^c \frac{dr}{r^{\alpha-1}}$$.

Answer (score 1):

> How does one find a primitive to the inner integral?

Separete $\alpha$ in two cases and substitute $u = x + y$.

If $\alpha = 1$ then
$$ \int_{0}^{1-x} \frac{1}{x+y}\ dy = \int_{x}^{1} \frac{1}{u}\ du = \log(1) - \log(x) = -\log(x)$$

Else
$$ \int \frac{1}{(x+y)^\alpha}\ dy = \int_{x}^{1} u^{-\alpha}\ du = \left.\frac{u^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha} \right|_{u=x}^{u=1} = \frac{1 - x^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha} $$

From here I believe it already can be seen that the second integral will converge only when $\alpha < 2$.

Answer (score -2):

**hint for the inner $\int $**

For $\alpha\ne 1$

$$\int_0^{1-x}\frac {dy}{(x+y)^\alpha}=$$
$$\Bigl [\frac {(x+y)^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}\Bigr]_0^{1-x} =$$

$$\frac {1}{1-\alpha}(1-x^{1-\alpha}) =$$

The double integral is
$$\frac {1}{2-\alpha} $$

If $\alpha=1$, we find $1$.

The double integral exists if $\alpha\ne 2$.

Comment: I actually got this far too, but I don't see how this helps me. After computing the entire integral I get $$I=\frac{1}{2-\alpha}.$$ So clearly $\alpha \neq 2$ but how can I show that $\alpha$ can't be greater than 2. How do I motivate this?

Comment: @Parseval: Convergence is just asking when does the integral give a real number i.e so long as $\alpha \not = 2$, the integral converges, why? because its value is $1/(2- \alpha)$.

Comment: That was my original thought, but the book says the answer is $a<2.$

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The behavior near the origin is like $r^{1-\alpha}$ where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. This will converge when $1-\alpha >-1$ (i.e., $\alpha < 2$)  and diverge otherwise. EDIT: RRL just added a correct answer above.